# How to leave a campaign you've been playing for a long time?

Tags: problem-players, group-dynamics, problem-gm, parting-ways-with-players

I've been playing a campaign for a while, a year or so (I know this isn't 'long' in terms of some campaigns but it's too long to just drop and say 'it's not my kinda playing style'). It's an online campaign - I didn't know anyone in the group pre-campaign, and whilst I've spoken to a few of them outside of the game, they're all a lot closer with one another than I am with any of them.

I have a few issues and I managed to deal with it for a while because someone else was having issues with the same player (who would steam roll other players; demand we did what they wanted and refuse to accept anyone elses ideas) and then the player left and I thought that was the end of it but now I'm finding a different player has just stepped in to do the exact same. Player B is not quite so aggressive and doesn't steam roll others ideas but the entire campaign is now focused on them. Any NPC connection is to them, to the point that whenever I want to talk to an NPC I take them out of the room to talk to them (and 90% of the time the other players just say they follow and steam roll me there instead).

I play a rogue so the only occasion to do things whilst reasonably not having the party nearby/interrupting constantly is dungeons.

I want to leave. I keep trying to come up with reasons to stay but find myself stuck.

I have put so many hours into this campaign, and don't get me wrong I have enjoyed the campaign but I am tired, so tired of being interrupted and ignored and treated like an idiot for not knowing things (I've been playing for 2 years, most of them have been playing for 10+ years)

How do I leave whilst letting the DM know that there's no hard feelings whilst being respectful and not making him feel bad and making sure everyone else knows I don't hate them or whatever?

[This other question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/bad-match-with-a-gaming-group-how-to-leave) is about how to leave a game you've been playing for a short while. I felt a separate question was needed due to having been with this group for a long time and thus it needs more... care? Either way it's not as simple as just leaving quietly.

Comment: This sounds like a DM problem. Are they aware of the problem or aware but unable to control it?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Another related question: [How should I deal with a difficult group and a DM that doesn't help?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/89178/how-should-i-deal-with-a-difficult-group-and-a-dm-that-doesnt-help)

Comment: What level is your character?  Is a dramatic exit within your own play style?

Comment: Assuming that you just want to leave and are not asking for specific help with specific other issues to try to stay, we have a good question with a bunch of answers already about how to exit a gaming group.  Interested folks, feel free and contribute new answers there.

Comment: Somehow I hadn’t caught this as marked a duplicate until I posted an answer.

Comment: @Greg0141 The dupe mark must have happened shortly after your completed your answer, since you'd not have been able to answer if the close action had been taken before you did.

Answer (score 3):

- Reach out to the DM and give them a chance to make adjustments.  If you aren’t satisfied, let him/her know that the next session will be your last (at least for a while).
- At the beginning of your next session, announce to the group what you’ve already conveyed to the DM (the group may not be shocked unless you’ve specifically asked the DM to allow you to tell the group).  Keep it positive and be sure to thank everybody (a joke or two never hurts in my experience).
- Switch gears and play the game.  And, play as though you weren’t leaving (not speaking of your PC, but rather of player attitude)
- Tie up any loose ends.
- Thank everyone again.
- Get out of the way.
- Reach out a few weeks later to see if they’re interested in going out for a beer.